# ¿Cómo puedo bloquear una fila en SQL?

Tags: sql, trigger

Estoy intentando bloquear las modificaciones de un campo de una tabla, ejemplo Tabla Productos y tiene 10 campos de los cuales quiero bloquear Precio y VentaBajoCosto, para que no se puedan hacer UPDATES pero en los campos restantes si pueda modificarlos. Ya intente con Trigger pero me bloquea todos los campos.
Este es el Trigger:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[Modificar_BajoCosto]
  on [dbo].[prods]
  for update
  as
   if update(BajoCosto)
   begin
    raiserror('No se puede vender por debajo.', 10, 1)
    rollback transaction
   end;
```

Comment: Bienvenido Jesus Orozco a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Añade por favor el código del trigger así podremos ayudarte mejor

Comment: En seguida lo agrego muchas gracias, ALTER trigger [dbo].[Modificar_BajoCosto]
  on [dbo].[prods]
  for update
  as
   if update(BajoCosto)
   begin
    raiserror('No se puede vender por debajo.', 10, 1)
    rollback transaction
   end;

Comment: Por lo que se ve, ya estarías bloqueando el `update` cuando actualizan la columna `BajoCosto`, ¿es esto lo que no funciona?¿o lo que no consigues es incorporar otra restricción en las otras columnas?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que bloquea toda la tabla, aun cuando le pongo la condición de que sea solo BajoCosto, es decir , con el trigger activo no puedo hacer modificaciones a ningún campo de la tabla y solo necesito bloquear el de BajoCosto

Comment: El `if update(BajoCosto) ... ` es correcto, solo debería disparar el error si se está actualizando esta columna, habría que ver cual es la sentencia  de `update` que estás corriendo y también que no exista en este u otro tirgger una actualización adicional de esta columna.

Comment: Muchas gracias, en efecto, había otro programa que afectaba la modificación de los campos, voy a proceder a revisar la opción que nos dan como respuesta, para ver si se soluciona, ya que el otro procesos no se puede eliminar o detener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Opción 1**

Utilizar un `Trigger instead of`.

```
Create Table dbo.prods
             (
             id          Int Primary Key
           , descripcion VarChar(10)
           , Precio      Int
           , BajoCosto   Int
           , otro        Int
             );
Go
Insert into dbo.prods 
(id, descripcion, Precio, BajoCosto, otro)
values
(1,'Prod a', 90, 25, 1),
(2,'Prod b', 80, 20, 2),
(3,'Prod c', 70, 15, 3),
(4,'Prod d', 60, 10, 4),
(5,'Prod e', 50, 5, 5);
GO
```

Tenemos el escenario.

```
Create trigger dbo.Modificar_BajoCosto on dbo.prods
instead of update
As
Begin
    With c as (
        Select i.id, i.descripcion, d.Precio, d.BajoCosto, i.otro
                from inserted i 
                join deleted d on i.id = d.id 
            )
    Update p set descripcion = c.descripcion,
                precio = c.Precio,
                BajoCosto= c.BajoCosto,
                otro = c.otro
        from dbo.prods p inner join c on p.id = c.id;

End;
go
```

El trigger instead of, es igual que el after update, pero se desencadena antes de la modificación, y tienes que realizar tú la sentencia de modificación.

En el caso, podemos meter los datos de las pseudoTablas `inserted` y `deleted`, que contienen los datos que había antes de la sentencia, y los que va a intentar establecer la sentencia, en una *tabla de expresión común*.

De la salida de la tabla de expresión común, recogemos los valores que se quieren cambiar para las columnas que nos interesan, a través de inserted y los que no queremos modificar a través de deleted.

Luego realizamos la update.

```
Update dbo.prods
       Set descripcion = 'Mod a'
         , precio = 100
         , Bajocosto = 100
         , otro = 21
Where id = 1;
```

[image: Resultado 1]

Si hacemos una update de varios registros también es válido.

```
Update dbo.prods
       Set descripcion = 'M'+descripcion
         , precio = precio*10
         , Bajocosto = BajoCosto*10
         , otro = otro*10
Where id > 1;
```

[image: Resultado 2]

Hay que tener cuidado con los cambios de `pk`, que este desarrollo no cubre.

**Opción 2**

Hacerlo en el `after update` como planteabas, pero realmente haces trabajar 2 veces al motor.

```
drop trigger dbo.Modificar_BajoCosto
go
Create trigger dbo.Modificar_BajoCosto on dbo.prods
after update
As
Begin
    With c as (
        Select i.id, i.descripcion, d.Precio, d.BajoCosto, i.otro
                from inserted i 
                inner join deleted d on i.id = d.id 
            )
    Update p set descripcion = c.descripcion,
                precio = c.Precio,
                BajoCosto= c.BajoCosto,
                otro = c.otro
                
        from dbo.prods p inner join c on p.id = c.id;

End;
```

[Trigger instead of](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/05/03/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-instead-of/)

[Trigger After update](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/15/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-update/)

Comment: Muchas gracias, la opción numero 1 es la que mas cumplió con las necesidades, agradezco mucho por tu tiempo y por detallar tan bien la respuesta